# Stop text view from going out of screen

Tags: android, android-studio

Im trying to make an app in android studio. I have a textview with a circular background. The thing is that when i install it on ta physical device the Text view goes of the screen.
Hers the preview in android studio:
[image]

The Xml code:

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout 

             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/top_bar">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"

           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:text="App name and image"

                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Pakistan vs Australia T20"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1.5dp"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="47dp"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="247dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Match Odds"
                        android:textColor="#ffff"
                        android:textSize="17dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Favourite"
                        android:textColor="#ffff"
                        android:textSize="17dp" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView12"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#ffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView11"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="-"
                            android:textColor="#ffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView10"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#ffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="WestIndies"
                        android:textColor="#ffff"
                        android:textSize="16dp"


                        android:visibility="visible" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"

                        android:background="@color/margins"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:background="@color/margins"
                        android:text="TextView" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Session"
                        android:textColor="#ffff"
                        android:textSize="17dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Runs/Balls"
                        android:textColor="#ffff"
                        android:textSize="17dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView17"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#FF0000"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView18"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="-"
                            android:textColor="#ffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView19"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#ffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextViewID"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/green_circle"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="#ff2800"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

What im getting on the screen:

[image]

ive tried using different devices with different screen sizes but all give the same result. How can i solve this.
TIA..!!!

Comment: zoraz, sorry for misleading you in my previous comment. - I deleted it. 
I’m pretty sure you just didn’t plan you layout widths. That’s all. Am I right? It’s not supposed to be straight forward as it seems, so you actually have to plan it. You mistake once, twice, then again and then on your real app you already know how to program and how to plan your views.

Comment: It will be better to use a `ConstraintLayout` to have a better-planned layout and avoid nested layouts. Also, with `ConstraintLayout` you can add a `Guideline` to the edges of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the `LinearLayout` where that round `TextView` is, is actually a child of another `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation, and you have another empty `LinearLayout` of width 250dp right before it, which pushes the relevant layout out of screen. Can you try removing the empty `LinearLayout` and see if it helps?

Comment: it works as the textView moves in but i need the LinearLayout to place some more text in...ill edit my post to make that clear

Comment: @zorazjavaid having a layout with hard-coded width (e,g 250dp) would make it so other views are pushed off-screen in smaller devices. What I would do if I were you is make the horizontal layout into a `RelativeLayout`, and then you can set the widths of both child-layouts into `match_parent`, and in the 2nd one (the one that holds the `TextView`), you can add `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"`, and in the left one set `android:layout_toStartOf="@id/otherLayoutId"`.

Comment: ok..ill try doing that and see how it goes..btw the preview screen is of a pixel 2 (5.0 inches) and im using a oppo f9 (6.3 inches).